# What are the <meta> tags for snapchat?

Tags: html, meta-tags, prerender, snapchat

I've put meta tags and am using prerender.io to have my webpage's dynamic ( as in the title changes every time) link preview show up when a link is shared on instagram, whatsapp, iOS messaging etc. However, on Snapchat when I message my link to friend, it doesn't work. On snapchat when my link is shared it just shows my old, default, unchanged title. Not the dynamic one I set.

I've tried looking everywhere for what Snapchat's meta tags are. I already have stuff like the following in my code for Facebook/Twitter:

```
<meta name="twitter:title" content="European Travel Destinations ">

<meta property="og:title" content="European Travel Destinations">
```

Was expecting my message on snapchat to have "my dynamic title" as the link preview. Instead it has "my undynamic title that's in my index.html" as the link preview. I currently have the title in the html update when on a specific webpage, this is why it works with whatsapp/instagram (thanks to prerender.io) but for some reason it's not working on snapchat